# Correct way to build up an Authorization header with Bearer and a variable for requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request-headers

What is the correct way to build up a request header in python for use with requests?

The header needs to be of the format:

"Authorization : Bearer ....token...." where ....token.... is a variable obtained from an OATH request made prior.

I tried:

```
auth_token_string = "Bearer "+token
api_headers = {}
api_headers["Authorization"] = auth_token_string
api_headers["x-api-key"] = "randomjazzhere"
api_headers["accept"] = "application/json"

print(api_headers)
result = requests.get(api_call_url, headers=api_headers)
result_json = result.json()
something = result.text
print(something)
```

It prints what appears to be correct formatted header, but the call fails, and the api is not more specific as to what the issue is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers are case sensitive and your `accept` header has lowercase "a", I am not sure but try making it uppercase as `Accept`.
Also a suggestion to restructure your code like:

```py
auth_token_string = "Bearer "+token
api_headers = {
    "Authorization": auth_token_string,
    "x-api-key": "randomjazz",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

print(api_headers)
result = requests.get(api_call_url, headers=api_headers)
result_json = result.json()
something = result.text
print(something)
```

If it still doesn't work, try changing the x in `x-api-key` to uppercase too (the mdn docs mention uppercase x, they also mention these are deprecated as of 2012)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations - I implemented them ( including the capitalized A and X ) - but unfortunately I still get the same issue.

Could it be the "Bearer" part that is giving the problem?

When the "constructed" url is run via curl as follow it works... (have to obtain a new token and substitute, but it works...)

curl -X GET "https://url.not.theactual.thing.com" -H 
"accept: application/json" -H 
"Authorization: Bearer eyJzXC......9ycCqg" -H 
"x-api-key: e6....U"

Comment: Could you show what exactly fails, the api must at least be returning an error message right?

Comment: It only says "403 forbidden"

Comment: OK, the issue was that the actual endpoint URL supplied to me was incorrect. Everything works perfectly now! Thanks for your assistance!